# Wrap lines at 80 characters

Tags: prelude, wrapping

I'm using emacs 25.1.1 with the [prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude) config. In Atom I used to have a setting that made my lines wrap at 80 characters (without cutting words) for better readability. I've searched on the web for something similar for emacs but I have not found anything. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: See command `auto-fill-mode` and variable `fill-column`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`auto-fill-mode` is what you're looking for. You can enable it automatically for editing text by adding this to your config:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook #'auto-fill-mode)
```

You can customize how long lines in your text documents should be by customizing the `fill-column` variable. For example:

```
(setq-default fill-column 80)
```

If you want to to make sure that lines don't split on your screen as you're typing things, you can set up [visual line mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Visual-Line-Mode.html).

To enable this for code files add:

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'auto-fill-mode)
```

This code needs to be added in your initialization file (`~/.emacs` or similar). That will make the change effective the next time you start emacs, so either do that now or close and reopen files that are already open.

Comment: Added those two lines to my config but it doesn't seem to do anything. Lines still continue beyond 80 characters...

Comment: The examples that I have provided will work only for editing text files, not code. Also, lines get wrapped when you type space or other character that doesn't belong it a word. I don't know how well `auto-fill-mode` would work for editing code.

Comment: Um, hm. And for editing code there is nothing like that? And what about org-mode?

Comment: `org-mode` is derived from `text-mode`, so this will work in it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to... Added that but lines still extend beyond the screen bounds.

Comment: In that case, you might be looking for this: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Visual-Line-Mode.html

Comment: That last thing worked beautifully! I also used this https://melpa.org/#/visual-fill-column to adjust it to the column width. Thanks!

Comment: Could you edit your answer with the new info so I can mark it as solved?