# What is the mode for org's LOGBOOK editing window and how can one be created if it doesn't already exist?

Tags: org-mode, hooks, fill-column

I want to wrap the LOGBOOK editing window at column width I'm yet to decide.

From another answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30221/wrap-lines-at-80-characters) I see need to set something along the lines of `(add-hook 'some-logbook-mode-hook #'auto-fill-mode)` and `(setq fill-column wrap-point)`

Does the `LOGBOOK` window have its own mode, or will I have to create a new mode for it if want to use a hook to set the mode?

Answer (score 0):

Open the logbook and use `C-h m` to find out what the major mode is. You’ll also find there any documentation for the mode, the keybindings that are active, and a link to the source code should you need it.

As a general rule, Emacs is intended to be self–documenting; you can always ask Emacs what is going on, and it always gives you as much information as it can. This includes the source code, with the ability to jump to the definition of any variable, function, mode, keymap, etc.